# Are these substituted transistors causing issues?

Tags: arduino, transistors, schematics

I'm working on building a copy of an open source project because the associated project is no longer being produced. I purchased all of the parts, and have assembled them according to the schematic, however, it has been to no avail. I'm wondering if it's possible that the transistors I chose are possibly not the correct ones for this, or maybe I have something arranged incorrectly.

The experienced issue is that the associated software can recognize the Arduino, but cannot send/receive correct commands/data through the transistors/device they're connected to. (Yellow is KFD_Sense, Green is KFD_Data, Black is ground)

The schematic/BOM calls for MMBT3904LT1G NPN transistors, which I replaced with non-SMD 2N3904 NPN transistors, and used typical resistors and Zener diodes.

What is missing/broken?

Here is the link to the project: [KFDShield](https://github.com/omahacommsys/KFDtool) and the previously sold [product](https://store.omahacomms.com/product/kfdshield/)

[image: Breadboard with circuit]
[image: Breadboard and Arduino connections]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: What are TPN transistors? The MMBT3904 is simply the SOT23 version of the 2N3904 (which comes in TO-92), so I can't imagine the substitution would change anything. But make sure you have the right pinout; pinout differs between packages.

Comment: @Hearth Sorry, misspelling. NPN transistors. In terms of pinouts, I wired them according to the schematic where the base is connected through the 1K ohm resistor to pin 4, emitter to ground, and collector to pin 2, 10K ohm to +5V, and 220 ohm resistor to the sense pin.

Comment: @Hearth and to your point that the substitution shouldn't change anything, I agree and am now completely stumped as to why this is not working.

Comment: @Hearth The GitHub readme for this project also suggests a basic hardware schematic example for those who would like to "build your own circuit on a breadboard" citing the minimum to get this project working is this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omahacommsys/KFDtool/master/doc/pic/basic_hw_schematic.png, but confusingly, the schematic has a totally different path where the KFD_sense connection is straight to ground?

Comment: They transistors look like they're wired correctly, I'm not sure how the connections to the UNO are supposed to be though. Have you verified that the transistor pinouts  match what a 2N3904 should be? These days it wouldn't be surprising to find some other transistor with a different pinout (such as BCE) marked as a 2N3904.

Comment: @GodJihyo You make an excellent point. Let me look into that to see if it has a weird pinout from where I bought them. I unfortunately don't have any equipment to check them physically though, unless there's a way I can do it only with an Arduino?

Comment: @GodJihyo I double checked the datasheet, and no changes, wired the same way as the schematic. I tried a few different transistors to see if they were bad but saw no changes.

Comment: I don't see a GND connection between UNO and breadboard GND. I stop looking after that: there may be more issues.

Comment: @glen_geek If you look reallllly closely, you'll see the long black wire connecting the ground rail on the breadboard to the  UNO.